# I don't find Small Talk option in DialogFlow ES

Tags: dialogflow-es

**The option does not exist in the place indicated by the DialogFlow ES documentation.**

*Integrated casual chat
Enable built-in casual chat for an agent
To enable built-in casual chat for your agent:
1 - Access the Dialogflow ES Console.
2 - Click Small Talk in the left sidebar menu.
3 - Activate the Enable option.
4 - Click Save.*

Reference documentation https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/agents-small-talk

[Documentation DialogFlow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8DzM.png)

[DialogFlow Platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndYZ3.png)

Comment: Could you provide a reference to (or image of) the documentation? You have tagged this as "smalltalk" and I'd like to know why. Is this related to the Smalltalk programming language?

Comment: Hi @JamesFoster! Thanks for the answer, I edited the question with the reference link and the images.

Comment: It does seem that the menu option is missing. Unfortunately I don't know anything about DialogFlow ES. (But thanks for removing the reference to Smalltalk!)